# OAuth Abstraction For Web Application With Multiple API's

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We have a web application (login page, etc) that calls a backend server (JWT) for all services. The backend server also exposes multiple API's (REST, SOAP) that utilize HTTP Basic Authentication. I am looking to migrating to OpenIDConnect and OAuth2 with the Spring Security toolset. I am trying to understand the correct configuration and the best way to integrate with identity providers like AzureAD.

The web application sounds like a OAuth Web application and a OAuth2 client. The backend server sounds like an OAuth resource servers for multiple API's.

What is the best way to model in AzureAD?

- Does each api have separate client id's?
- Better to have common authorities pool or specific to each api?

Looking for any insight and recommendations.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: By having separate client IDs for every it will be easy to monitor and manage permissions for each API separately.

Implementing common authorities pool will make application's configuration easier but difficult to monitor and manage permissions for each API if there are more APIs.

**Hence**, you can try creating separate Azure AD Application for every API (REST, SOAP). It is useful for auditing and security purposes.

Based on your requirement, you can make use [**Authentication Flows**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#scenarios-and-supported-authentication-flows) to authentication the Application.

Create an **Azure AD Application** and add API permissions:

[image]

Generate an **access token** to call the API:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, the assigned permissions are displayed like below:

[image]

By using the above access token, you can call the API:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

[image]